# Хватит замораживать вопросы!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Перевод слова "closed" по отношению к вопросу не вызывает вопросов, пардон за каламбур: вопрос "закрыт". Это общепринятый термин, и ни у кого не вызывает сомнений, что он значит. Слово употребляется и на традиционных форумах, и в повседневной жизни.

Но что же, чёрт побери, такое "замороженный" вопрос? На традиционных форумах такого понятия нет и никогда не было. В повседневной жизни замороженность вопроса означает, что некие высшие силы решили больше не заниматься вопросом и потому отложили в долгий ящик.

У новичка, который видит, что его вопрос "заморожен", возникает естественная реакция: ах вы гады-паразиты, вы меня игнорировать решили, видеть мой вопрос не хотите, отвечать брезгуете, да чтоб вас!

Но ведь "on hold" означает совсем другое! Это словосочетание означает совсем не понижение температуры вопроса до абсолютного нуля или засовывание вопроса куда подальше власть имущими. Часто оно означает, что на вопрос в его текущей форме нельзя дать краткий содержательный ответ, что от автора вопроса ожидают более подробное описание проблемы. Даже причины для закрытия из категории "оффтопик" в большинстве своём предполагают, что вопрос можно доработать, чтобы он соответствовал критериям качества.

Посмотрим в [словарь](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=on+hold&l1=1):

- без движения
- включение в резерв
- не завершено
- под вопросом
- в состоянии ожидания
- заблокированный
- приостановлено
- уточняется

...и ни слова про заморозку.

Как вам кажется, стоит ли менять перевод пометки "[заморожен]" на вопросах? Если да, то какой перевод вам кажется наиболее подходящим?

Comment: А кстати, в чём проблема с длинной строкой?

Comment: @VladD Длинные заголовки выглядят не очень эстетично. Перенос в заголовке — фу, гадость!

Comment: Сменить "заморожен" на менее обидное "надо уточнить" это, конечно, правильно. Однако, больше беспокоит закрытие (а по сути, что заморожен, что требует уточнения это почти на 100% закрыть (согласен, многие на самом деле дурацкие вопросы надо закрывать и удалять)) *по причине*: **Вопросы с просьбами предоставить рекомендации или найти книги, инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие внешние ресурсы являются на Stack Overflow вопросами не по теме, так как приводят к спорам и спаму**. Вот такой причины (скажем, на просьбу посоветовать библиотеку) не должно быть вообще.

Comment: @avp: Это да, возможно, стоит обсудить это отдельной темой?

Comment: Возможно. Хотя, зачем их плодить?

Comment: Ну, тогда на неё больше людей обратят внимание. Комментарии почти никто не читает, кроме энтузиастов. (Впрочем, ходят ли неэнтузиасты на мету?)

Comment: @avp Лучше плодить и размножать, чем обсуждать политику модерирования в узком кругу переводчиков.

Comment: "Заморожен" это нормальный перевод "on hold", то, что его нет в словаре это исключительно проблема словаря - всех вариантов не перечислишь. Я не понимаю, почему у некоторых "заморожен" вызывает негативные эмоции. Заморожен означает, что нечто было приостановлено до наступления определенных условий, когда это нечто будет разморожено. Какое другое слово в русском языке подойдёт лучше - мне не ясно.

Comment: @Discord, просто я заранее знаю результат обсуждения такой темы. Поэтому воздействие текста в комментариях не отличается от его же  воздействия в открытой теме.

Comment: @avp Если вопрос будет чуть менее, чем полностью, состоять из истошных воплей "ах вы, козлы, раззакрывались, чтоб вам пусто было, жить не даёте!!!" — результат очевиден, да. Если написать содержательный вопрос, проанализировать сложившуюся ситуацию, взвесить плюсы и минусы, ознакомиться с аргументацией на МСО и МСЕ и упомянуть связанные обсуждения с разбором их выводов — результат может быть совсем другим. У меня по этой теме вообще сложная позиция, я её двумя словами выразить не могу.

Comment: заморожен идиотский статус, пока не прочитал тут что это значит вообще немог понять что это значит, тут говорят что "зато он универсальный" , но именно его универсальность и не даёт понять сходу что это значит, лично я думал что заморожен=забанен/закрыт ps : надо делать как удобнее а не как "у них"

Comment: Поддерживаю автора - долго ломал голову, что может обозначать это слово в данном контексте. Ни на одном форуме не встречал такого. если б не увтдел это обсуждение , так и остался б в неведении.

Comment: @Discord: Отредактировал локализацию согласно выигравшему с отрывом варианту (и учитывая [остальные формы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517/10105)).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Заморозка - отличный термин, особенно если мы знаем как работает Stack Overflow. К сожалению, должен согласиться, что тремин `[заморожен]` *может быть* непонятен новичкам. Назначение данного статуса - показать, что вопрос нуждается в улучающей правке. К предложенному выше, спешу предложить следующее.

### [требует правки]

Comment: На мой взгляд все эти варианты хуже [заморожен], т.к. [заморожен] покрывает все эти варианты, тогда как каждый из этих вариантов лишь частично покрывает требуемый функционал. На мой взгляд, те пользователи, что обижаются на [заморожен] будут обижаться на любой другой статус. Тут дело не в статусе, а в самом факте закрытия, как мне кажется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, разделите ответ, а то голосовать невозможно.

Comment: @ixSci Надпись "on hold" появилась исключительно чтобы юзеры не обижались. Функционально это полностью эквивалентно "closed", единственное отличие — автоматическое попадание в очредь на переоткрытие при правке. Поэтому и переводить следует нейтрально, а не слишком похоже на "closed", чтобы у юзера сложилось корректное впечатление о состоянии.

Comment: @Discord, а разве "заморожен" похоже на "closed"? На мой взгляд лучше чем "заморожен" придумать крайне затруднительно.

Comment: @ixSci "Заморожен" похоже на окончательный приговор, хоть и в несколько меньшей степени, чем "закрыт". До новичка очень желательно ясно донести мысль, что вопрос следует улучшить и переоткрыть.

Comment: @Discord, ну вот тут мы вступаем в конфликт ассоциаций, для меня "заморожен" это более емкий синоним слова "приостановлен". Кроме того, не все вопросы будут переоткрыты. К примеру, давайте возьмём вопрос "Лучший ORM-фреймворк для C++". Мы его закроем, т.к. по правилам такие вопросы запрещены и если там будет не "заморожен", а "требует уточнения", то это будет глупо, потому что никакого уточнения не требуется и этот вопрос не будет переоткрыт, пока правила не изменятся.

Comment: @ixSci Если автору нужна не "лучшая ORM либа", а вообще-то у него есть конкретные проблемы/требования, то вопрос можно переформулировать, чтобы он вписывался в правила. К сожалению, как на большом СО, так и здесь, у большинства юзеров проблемы с такими нюансами, и в результате механически закрываются абсолютно все вопросы, которые хоть отдалённо соответствуют какой-нибудь причине закрытия. На существование списка "[как правильно задавать субъективные вопросы](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)" абсолютному большинству покласть. (Это к вопросу о том, почему нет причины "домашнее задание".)

Comment: @ixSci: По факту, для новичков «заморожен» не означает побуждения к улучшению вопроса. В этом слове не видно возможности повлиять на события. Поэтому они просто бросают вопрос. Да, я знаю, что on hold не лучше.

Comment: _[заблокирован]_ уже есть среди вариантов

Comment: @Nicolas: По результатам голосования можно править перевод?

Comment: @VladD Вполне. На старой Мете было правило двух дней. Если что-то пойдет не так всегда можно поменять обратно!

Comment: Фактическая практика показывает, что такая плашка ложна. Она прикрепляется к вопросам, которые не требует правки, а значит противоречит истине и вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: Ах да. Предлагаю заменить ссылку «переоткрыть» на «перетребовать правки» ;) Локализировать- так до конца.

Comment: Существует т.н. контекстуальный перевод. Здесь как раз-таки этот случай.

Comment: @ReinRaus К примеру, вопрос плохой, его следует закрыть или удалить и забыть о нем. В большинстве случаев, наверное, так следовало бы и поступить, но все же мы надеемся, что если вопрос будет отмечен как требующий правки, а не закрыт/удален, то автор внесет улучшающие изменения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, если приняли новый перевод, его желательно использовать везде. Например сейчас в [справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) это состояние по прежнему указано, как "заморожено". Вероятно следует в справке проверить и остальные термины, которым меняли перевод, т.к. "заморожено" мне просто сразу в глаза бросилось.

Comment: @Olter Да, вы правы. Тоже заметил ошибку. [Nick Volynkin уже начал обсуждения педакции](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654/).

Answer (score 5):

## [нужно уточнение]

В качестве альтернативного варианта к *[уточняется]*, подчёркивает необходимость действия. Из минусов — возможно, слишком длинное?

Comment: А если мы закрыли вопрос, как "не по теме", что там уточнять?

Comment: @ixSci В группе причин закрытия "не по теме" в основном что угодно, но не "не по теме". Просьба рекомендовать внешний ресурс должна быть переформулирована (как решить проблему, а не перечислить все ресурсы), "почему код не работает?" явно описывает требуемые исправления, в ручные причины у нас чаще всего вводят текст про домашние задания, и в этом случае тоже требуется указать конкретную проблему при решении. Ну да, остаётся "опечатка". Но невелика беда, такие вопросы вообще удалять надо, а не закрывать.

Answer (score 2):

## [Требует улучшения]

Не просто поправить вопрос надо, а улучшить. Подразумевает, что сейчас он задан в плохой, неподходящей форме.

Answer (score 0):

Следующий вариант.

### [требует уточнения]

Answer (score 0):

Оставить как есть

### [заморожен]

Answer (score 0):

## [ Закрыт ]

Странно, почему нет самого лучшего варианта, который всем понятен и давно прижился, который точно описывает что произошло с вопросом- вопрос «Закрыт» и он либо останется в таком виде до конца веков, либо с ним надо что-то сделать и его переоткроют, ведь есть же для чего-то кнопка «переоткрыть» под закрытыми вопросами.

Comment: Проблема в том, что «закрыт» означает для новичка «окончательно закрыт», и это не мотивирует его улучшить/исправить вопрос.

Comment: @VladD лучше в туре по сайту указать, что если вопрос закрыли, то наверно стоит его исправить. Или присвоить плашку «Требует правки» нескольким конкретным причинам закрытия (как «копия» сделана только для копий). Всем остальным причинам закрытия вешать плашку «Закрыт». У плашки «Закрыт» есть более серьезная проблема: на хэшкоде видел как некоторые участники начинали закрывать свои вопросы по причине «ответ получен и принят». Это быстро лечилось переоткрытием этих вопросов и парой комментариев, что так делать не надо.

Comment: Проблема в том, что новички не читают документацию :-( (Ну и тур обычно останавливается больше на позитивных моментах.)

Answer (score 0):

Мне не нравится [требует правки], потому что бывают вопросы, которые правкой не спасти. Например, opinion-based вопросы типа «где ставить фигурную скобку в Java-коде». Как его исправить, чтобы открыли?

Мои варианты:

**[кандидат на закрытие]**

**[в очереди на закрытие]**

Comment: Ваш пример не очень удачный. Вопрос о скобке можно спасти, превратив его в «Есть ли общепринятый coding standard в Java, и если есть, то какой?»

Comment: "Кандидат на закрытие" и "в очереди на закрытие" не отражает, что нужно сделать, чтобы этого избежать. Помечать таким все вопросы, многие из которых можно исправить, думаю, не очень разумно, так как будет демотивировать.

Answer (score -1):

## [нужно уточнить]

или

## [надо уточнить]

Вариация [версии @VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395). Отглагольные существительные попахивают канцеляритом, да и с глаголом короче получается (хоть и всего на одну букву). Правда всё равно длинновато, на мой вкус.

Answer (score -2):

## [уточняется]

Как мне кажется, именно последнее слово из Мультитрана довольно точно описывает состояние вопроса. Автор вопроса должен его *уточнить*. При этом слово достаточно краткое, поэтому в названии заголовка оно будет смотреться гармонично.

В идеале, конечно, было бы желательно донести до автора вопроса, что вопрос не сам по себе уточняется, а именно автор должен его уточнить, но я не знаю, как выразить эту мысль кратко.

Comment: А если нечего уточнять? Если вопрос вообще не по теме?

Comment: тогда его удалят рано или поздно

Comment: @Nofate, до того как его удалят [уточняется] явно будет не в тему.

Comment: "Уточняется" может быть воспринято неправильно: как будто кто-то уточняет какие-то вещи в вопросе (можно не принять это на свой счёт, как призыв к действию, если задал вопрос и получил такую метку).

Answer (score -2):

## [заморожен]

или

## [отморожен]

Нечего сюсюкаться с новичками! Если вопрос заморожен — значит, заморожен! У нас тут валидация: не нравится — вали!

Comment: Второй звучит как оскорбление: `[отморозок]`

Answer (score -2):

Следующий вариант.

### [приостановлен]

Comment: Похоже по запутыванию на исходный вариант

Comment: вопрос не может быть приостановлен, это неграмотно.

Answer (score -4):

## [заблокирован]

У кого там психологические проблемы? Проваливайте, вы нам не нужны! Ваш вопрос заблокирован, вы в списках на удаление! Выхода нет, вы проиграли.

Пусть остаются только те, кто читает объяснение шрифтом нормального размера. Даже не мелким, заметьте.

Comment: путаница с locked вопросами

Answer (score -4):

Вариация слова "блокировка", которое более явно показывает, что вопрос следует исправить.

### [заблокирован]

### [блокирован]

Answer (score -5):

## [вызывает сомнения]

## [поставлен под сомнение]

По-моему, такое название метки ясно даёт понять, что вопрос поставлен некорректно, и не задевает чувства спрашивающих. При этом не указывает на необходимость действия (об этом можно прочитать в подсказке).
И, возможно, оно слишком длинное?

Comment: в качестве варианта _[мутный какой-то]_

Comment: По моим ощущениям, "сомнение" -- это не то слово, которое правильно поймёт человек, задавший вопрос.