# Вопрос требует правки — как переводить связанные фразы?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

Не так давно [мы коллективно решили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393/10105), что перевод термина ‘on hold’ должен быть «требует правки», а не «заморожен».

Однако, есть несколько мест, в которых я не могу сообразить, как правильно перевести, и прошу помощи клуба. Я не очень доволен качеством получающегося текста. Ниже приведён список строк, содержащих ‘on hold’, с их переводами:

- My question was closed or put on hold

  - было: Мой вопрос был закрыт или заморожен
  - будет: Мой вопрос был закрыт или отмечен требующим правки (?)
- You cannot include [on hold] in the title.

  - было: Нельзя использовать [заморожено] в заголовке.
  - будет: Нельзя использовать [требует правки] в заголовке.
- on hold

  - было: заморожен
  - будет: требует правки
- put on hold

  - было: заморозить
  - будет: потребовать правку (?) или объявить требующим правки (??)
- Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be put on hold by experienced community members. While questions are on hold, they can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.

  - было: Вопросы, которые требуют доработки или которые не подходят для данного сайта, могут быть заморожены опытными участниками сообщества. Во время заморозки вопрос можно отредактировать, чтобы он стал соответствовать правилам, после чего он может быть открыт снова.
  - будет: Вопросы, которые требуют доработки или которые не подходят для данного сайта, могут быть отмечены опытными участниками сообщества. Если вопрос отмечен требующим правки, его можно отредактировать, чтобы он стал соответствовать правилам, после чего он может быть открыт снова.
- Why is my question closed or on hold?

  - было: Почему мой вопрос закрыт или заморожен?
  - будет: Почему мой вопрос закрыт или отмечен требующим правки?
- [on hold]

  - было: [заморожен]
  - будет: [требует правки]
- **put on hold** as $closeReason$ $onDate$

  - было: **заморожен** по причине $closeReason$ $onDate$
  - будет: объявлен $onDate$ **требущим правки**, так как $closeReason$
- **put on hold** as $closeReason$ by $userCommas$ $onDate$

  - было: **заморожен** по причине $closeReason$ пользователем $userCommas$ $onDate$
  - будет: объявлен $onDate$ **требущим правки** пользователем $userCommas$, так как $closeReason$

---

**Обновление**: по результатам обсуждения внёс правки в перевод, они должны выкатиться со следующий обновлением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спешу предложить использовать "отмечен" вместо "объявлен".

- My question was closed or put on hold

  - Мой вопрос был закрыт или требует правки
  - Мой вопрос был закрыт или отмечен требующим правки
- put on hold

  - запросить правку
  - отметить требующим правку
- Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be put on hold by experienced community members. While questions are on hold, they can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.

  - Вопросы, которые требуют доработки или которые не подходят для данного сайта, могут быть отмечены опытными участниками сообщества. Если вопрос отмечен требующим правки, его можно отредактировать, чтобы он стал соответствовать правилам, после чего он может быть открыт снова.
- **put on hold** as $closeReason$ $onDate$

  - отмече $onDate$ **требущим правки**, так как $closeReason$
- **put on hold** as $closeReason$ by $userCommas$ $onDate$$userCommas$ $onDate$

  - будет: отмечен $onDate$ **требущим правки** пользователем $userCommas$, так как $closeReason$

Comment: «запросить правку» звучит вроде бы хорошо