# Разморозить документацию!

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, термины, справка, причины-закрытия

## Кратко: две задачи:

1. [v] Заменить термин "заморожен" на "требует правки" в тексте.
2. [v] Заменить старые причины закрытия новыми и написать к ним уточняющий текст.

## В ответах к этому вопросу

Предлагаю в ответах написать варианты объяснения причин закрытия. Всё ради того, чтобы [добиться улучшающих правок от авторов закрытых вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/545/181472).

## Долго и подробно

Достаточно давно обсуждалась [замена термина "вопрос заморожен" на "требует правки"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393/181472). Однако, [соответствующая страница документации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) до сих пор рассказывает о замороженных вопросах:

> **Что означает статус вопроса “закрыт” или “ заморожен”? Почему часть вопросов находится в состоянии “заморожено”?**
>
> **Почему часть вопросов находится в состоянии “заморожен”?**
>
> Вопросы, требующие доработки или не совсем подходящие для данного сайта, могут быть заморожены опытными участниками сообщества. На замороженные вопросы нельзя отвечать, но их можно редактировать, чтобы их можно было снова открыть.
>
> Вопросы, отредактированные в течение пяти дней со времени заморозки, автоматически отправляются в очередь на повторное открытие для правки сообществом. Вопросы, не открытые заново в течение пяти дней, меняют свое состояние с `[заморожен]` на `[закрыт]`.

Более того, [недавно сменились формулировки причин закрытия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/545/181472). Похоже, что изменения ещё не устаканились и необходимо некоторое время, чтобы согласовать и зафиксировать новые причины закрытия. Когда это произойдет (а лучше - при каждом изменении), необходимо переписать вторую часть этого документа, которая объясняет причины закрытия.

> - вопрос непонятен - иногда нам требуется больше информации, чтобы помочь решить вашу проблему.
>
> > Уточните вашу конкретную проблему или предоставьте дополнительную информацию, которая поможет понять, что именно вам требуется. Текущая формулировка вопроса не позволяет понять, о чем вы спрашиваете.
>
> Отредактируйте ваше сообщение, чтобы оно конкретнее описывало то, что вы ищете и не забудьте ответить на все замечания, которые другие пользователи оставили в комментариях.

Comment: Исправлено. Имеет смысл закрыть вопрос на мете.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Хватит замораживать вопросы!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393/%d0%a5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b)

Comment: Вроде не дубликат из-за второго пункта.